# How can I get the next Item in a ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Im dealing with Media files. 
When for example a song ends, I want the ListView to select the next song in the list. 
So in general I want to get the next Item after the selected Item.

Comment: Hi, please add the code to help understanding your problem

Comment: There is no code, its just a normal ListView from JavaFX.

Comment: do you all have the same homework ;) There's a similar question just a couple of days ago, do some research .. Anyway, this question is far too broad, too many possibilities what your exact problem might be: so learn how to use a List, learn how to access its items, learn how to use the selectionModel (hint: there's api doc and tutorials for all this) and if after all that you are stuck at a concrete problem, come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what doesn't work out like you expect it :)

Comment: hmm .. or was the question I seem to remember your own that you deleted for some reason? If so, better not - you would be wasting all our time ;)

Comment: Hm well its not a homework in the first case, and this is my first question ever asked in this forum. And as you might realised there is no such a question anymore. Because I did search for it and ended up in a "How can I get the selected Item of a ListView" which I did not ask. Belive it or not :)

Comment: The same solution presented here for `TableView` should also work for `ListView`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179474/how-to-select-highlight-next-row-in-tableview-javafx/54179842#54179842

Comment: Thats also pretty good thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code to how to iterate over the elements in your ListView:

```
ObservableList<MediaFile> items = listView.getItems();
items.forEach(mediaFile) -> {
    //Custom logic... 
    if (mediaFile.equals(currentMediaFile)) {
    ...
    }
});
```

I think you can implement a logic from this point on. You can also try using an **Iterator** over this list in order to find the next element after the currently selected element. Here is a simple tutorial for the iterator:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Comment: certainly possible and all true, given the wobbly problem description :) For a potentially better answer (and to learn the options yourself :), you might want to read the api doc of SelectionModel - as that's the only concrete hint the OP gave ..